# Get user IP from remote script

Tags: javascript, api, remote-access

I have a page which loads a script from a remote location (say `myscript.com`.

This scripts makes an Ajax request to a distant API.

How can this API get the visitor's IP address?

If I use `request.remote_addr` in the request handler, I get the IP from the script's location (`myscript.com`).

Comment: Have you considered to run the remote script with the visitor's IP as an argument of your script ?

Comment: @William I'm aware of this possibility but would like to avoid it as it delays the Ajax call (having to wait for a remote dedicated IP API response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this api to get all this data as a json who visited your page
 `{"as":"AS9583SifyLimited","city":"Bengaluru","country":"India","countryCode":"IN","isp":"Sify Limited","lat":12.9833,"lon":77.5833,"org":"Sify Limited","query":"202.191.210.194","region":"KA","regionName":"Karnataka","status":"success","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","zip":"560099"}`

```
 API_Location=' http://ip-api.com/json';
            $.getJSON( API_Location)
              .done(function( position ) {
                  if (position.lat && position.lon) {
                    updateWeather(position);
                } else {
                    updateWeather({"lat":DEFAULT_LAT, "lon":DEFAULT_LON});
                }
              })
              .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
                var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
            });
```

visit this page [ip](http://ip-api.com/json) and you can get how to get ip!